# Add authentication headers when redirecting to deep link

Tags: firebase, http-headers, firebase-dynamic-links

I am using firebase dynamic links as a URL shortener/obfuscator. E.g. I want my firebase link to point to a file in a github repo I can set the deeplink to:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Username/repo/...
```

The issue is to call that deep link I need an authentication header.

Is there anyway to tell firebase, when I send a GET request to `https://<mydomain>.page.link/friendlyName` - it should ultimately direct to `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Username/repo/...` and add an authentication header

```py
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'token github_pat_xyzxyzxyz'
}
```

Is this possible or am I misunderstanding how deep links work?

Answer (score 1):

A dynamic link in Firebase should contain all necessary information. There is no way to dynamically add parameters or headers to the request once the dynamic link is clicked.

What you *can* do is set up your own redirection service (for example on Cloud Functions or Cloud Run) that adds the required header and then send the request on to GitHub.